# Windows authentication with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, authentication

I use Eclipse daily for software development and those of you that use it know that you download plugins and updates regularly. The company I work for has Bluecoat installed, which blocks all of the updates. However, the update URLs are not blocked in Internet Explorer. With this said, the problem seems to be that Eclipse is not using Windows authentication when it requests updates from the URLs. Is there a way to set Eclipse up so that it acts like IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be linked to the proxy and not to Bluecoat:
If IE does authorized the access to update URLs, it must do so through an authenticated proxy connection.

If you do have such a setting (proxyname:port , user/password), you should report that setting on your eclipse, in order for p2 within that eclipse to use those same settings.

(Menu `Preferences : General / Network Connections`)

Comment: Same problem here and _your_ answer is the solution :)